# Powershell script easy true false

Tags: powershell

Looking to see if there is an easier way to do this?  It seems like I should be able to get a positive or negative in a little more simple fashion.

```
$svc = GWMI Win32_Service @prm
    if (($svc | ? {$_.Name -match "Symantec Antivirus"}).State -match "Running") {
        $SEPRun = "Yes"
        }
    else {
        $SEPRun = "No"
        }
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but what does the `@prm` do? I can't find this out.

Comment: @Dangph It is called 'splatting' and it allows you to pass parameters in a hashtable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want $isRunning set to $true or $false, all you should need is this:

```
$isRunning = (GWMI Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Symantec Antivirus'").state -eq 'Running'
```

If you really want it to be either 'Yes' or 'No', you can use a switch instead of the If/Else

```
$isRunning = 
switch ((GWMI Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Symantec Antivirus'").state -eq 'running') 
{ True {'Yes'} False {'No'} }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start you might filter with the Get-Wmi command, and if I may guess you look for any process running rather than the latest in the list of services the test is better without the else-clause.

```
$SEPRun = $false;
(GWMI Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Symantec Antivirus'") | % { if($_.State -eq "Running")
{$SEPRun = $true} }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `Filter` parameter on `Get-WmiObject`. You can combine multiple criteria using logical operators AND and OR. For example your query is simply

```
$isRunning = (gwmi Win32_Service @prm -Filter "Name LIKE '%Symantec Antivirus%' AND State = 'Running'" | measure-object).Count -gt 0
```

Also, 'Symantec Antivirus' sounds like a DisplayName not a Name. For example the Windows Update service on my machine has a DisplayName of 'Windows Update' and a Name of 'wuauserv'.